# Loading failed for the <script> with source when mix with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox

I have javascript script which I am generating using php. Lets call it js.php , when I put raw text inside and try to link it from other page it works fine. Moment I add php code into script I get

Loading failed for the < script > with source

js.php

```
< ?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

? >

console.log('javascript is loaded');
```

If I remove the php code from the top file loads fine, moment add it back it gives me error, I have check in firefox and chrome the same issue

Comment: remove spaces between `<` and `?php`

Comment: `text/javascript` is the correct mime type, afaik

Comment: Though really, if you are giving a <script> tag the url for this php file, I'm not sure why you need either of these headers.

Comment: Without header it doesn't work either, it needs to have no php code at all to work

Comment: A php file will be turned into a response.  If you do not have `<?php ?>` in the file it will be treated as just a text file, and what the text is will be the response.  Since you are not doing an ajax call, CORS is not an issue so the first header does not make sense.  And since you are putting it in a script tag, the page knows that it should be treated as a script file, so the content type header doesn't make sense.

Comment: so, what to do to be able to load into <script ...